# About calculation of auto correlation function

Tags: probability

Problem: There are two coins, a fair one F and a biased one B with $P(head)=1/4$. For the first toss F is chosen with probability 1/3. For the subsequent tosses, a coin is chosen depending on the previous toss result: F following a head. B following a tail. A binary random process $X_{n}$ is generated by the tosses such that in the $n$th toss. $X_{n}=1$ if a head appears and $X_{n}=0$ otherwise.
In this situation what is autocorrelation function $R_{X}(k)$ for $k=-2,-1,0,1,2$

My approach:

First i checked is it strict-sense stationary

$$P(X_{1}=1)=\frac{1}{3},P(X_{1}=0)=\frac{2}{3}$$

$$P(X_{2}=1)=\frac{1}{3},P(X_{2}=0)=\frac{2}{3}$$

$$P(X_{n}=1)=\frac{1}{3},P(X_{n}=0)=\frac{2}{3}$$

so i concluded that $X_{n}$ is strict sense stationary

And using autocorrelation function definition, defined autocorrelation function like below
$$R_{X}(k)=E[X_{n}X_{n+k}]$$

And using strict sense stationary property of $X_{n}$, redefine autocorrelation function like $R_{X}(k)=E[X_{n}^{2}]$ ($X_{n}=X_{n+k}$ due to strict sense stationary)

So my answer is $R_{X}(k)=\frac{1}{3}$ for $k=-2,-1,0,1,2$

Am i correct?

If there are mistake please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: No.  $X_n$ and $X_{n+k}$ may have the same distribution but (unless $k=0$) they are not always equal.

Comment: Can you give me more detail explanation?